# How to fix flipping matrices into good rotation matrices?

Tags: determinant, rotations

According to ["Finding the Nearest Orthonormal Matrix"](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Nearest_Orthonormal_Matrix.pdf) paper, I am finding rotation matrices by the formula

$R = M (M^TM)^{-1/2}$

Unfortunately, sometimes this formula gives

$|R|=-1$

i.e. not rotation, but flipping matrix. In such cases I am inverting sign of one column to invert the determinant and this gives me good rotation matrix.

I have a feeling, not proved, that this matrix is rotated by $\pi$ radians relative to wished. So, how to rotate it back by $\pi$ radians? Can I just multiply this matrix by

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

(in 2D case)

Comment: Yes, rotation by $\pi$ is the same as negation. I'm not sure about the rest of your question, but I don't think the negative of a reflection will magically become a rotation or vice versa.

Comment: I am negating one column first. But I understand, that negating one column then negating entire matrix is the same as negating another column

Comment: Usually this comes up in connection with an SVD, and since a closest approximation is desired, one flips the axis corresponding to the smallest singular value.

Comment: I found the following in the paper’s introductory paragraph amusing: “While this two step approach — first finding a “best fit’’ matrix without enforcing orthonormality, and then finding the nearest orthonormal matrix — is not to be recommended...”

Comment: @amd I think they mention this because it's usually more precise to incorporate the orthonormality constraint directly into the problem you're trying to solve instead of trying to patch the result. This way, the resulting rotation matrix will be the best that solves the problem with the actual data, and not the closest to the best general transformation using a metric that may not at all relate to the actual problem.